# Display icon when at least one checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I display checkboxes in my table. Now when i check at least one checkbox, the icon must appear if not, it should be hidden. My icon is not hidden. 
What am i doing wrong?

This is my code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 ">
    <a data-toggle="modal" id="btnAdd" data-target="#myModal" class="btn"> Add Items </a> 

    <i type="icon" class="fa fa-trash " ></i>


<div>   
</div>
<table class="table" id="table"> 
    <thead>
        <tr> 
          <th><input type="checkbox" id="master"></th>                           
        </tr>

    </thead>
<tbody>
 <td><input type="checkbox"></td>                           


//table data here
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>


var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    hideIcon = $("i[type='icon']");

checkboxes.click(function() {
    hideIcon.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: Provide full code. Without HTML provided solution can't be complete

Comment: please check my update @MarioNikolaus

Comment: Your HTML is malformed, can you provide actual code you are using...

Comment: @MarioNikolaus i just edited it. I am actually using this code. just that i took out the `td`

Comment: @LearnLaravel is it your intention to set a `disabled` attribute on the icon or do you actually want to hide it with something like `style="display:none"`?

Comment: @CharlieWeems, i am trying to hide it like `style="display:none"` not disable actually

Comment: Add your icon the class `icon` or something else and select it with it.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to iterate through all your checkboxes on each click. Also, I would recommend using the `prop` function to check for the "checked" status. Then, to hide it, either use the `hide` function, or set the `display` property to `hidden`:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
  var atLeastOneChecked = false;
  $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).prop('checked'))
      atLeastOneChecked = true;
  });
  if (atLeastOneChecked) {
    $("i[type='icon']").show(); //built-in jquery function
    //...or...
    $("i[type='icon']").css('display','inline-block'); //or set style explicitly
  } else {
    $("i[type='icon']").hide(); //built-in jquery function
    //...or...
    $("i[type='icon']").css('display','none'); //set style explicitly
  }
});
```

Comment: which attribute can i use to hide it actually?

Comment: Didn't realize you were wanting to change that too. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @LearnLaravel you might also want to give your icon a specific id so that you don't inadvertently hide a different icon.

Comment: @MattSpinks this is doing the opposite of what i want actually :). I slightly updated my table too

Comment: Did you want the icon to show when none are selected, or to show when >0 is/are selected?

Comment: on page load, the icon shouldn't show because no checkbox is selected. when one at least checkbox is checked, the icon must show. If user deselects all checkbox, the icon should disappear